# setting different window title for different IWizardPages

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

I have a JFace Wizard and I want to set different window title for different wizard page. Currently I've overridden method named as `setWindowTitle` and I'm calling this method from wizard pages, but title is not appearing on wizard page.

Code on wizard is

```
@Override
public void setWindowTitle(String newTitle) {
    super.setWindowTitle(newTitle);
}
```

And on JFace WizardPage is

```
private InstallationWizard iWizard = new InstallationWizard();
        iWizard.setWindowTitle(PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(Constants.QTL_INSTALLATION_WIZARD_1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `getWindowTitle()` in your wizard like this:

```
@Override
public String getWindowTitle() {
    if (getContainer() != null) {
        IWizardPage currentPage = getContainer().getCurrentPage();

        if (currentPage == wizardPage1)
            return "title1";
        else if (currentPage == wizardPage2)
            return "title2";
    }

    return "otherwise";
}
```